# Write a code that connects and reads the mounted storage on a azure web app using python flask?

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I have an app service with path mapping to my blob storage. I was wondering how I can code an application that reads the contents within that?

```
from flask import Flask
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "<h1>Hello Azure!</h1>"
    # getContents()


# def getContents():
#     with open('client.txt') as json_file:
#         data = json.load(json_file)
#         print(data)
```

thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate an url with sas token for your images as blobs in the private container using the funtion `generate_container_sas` or `generate_blob_sas` of Azure Blob Storage SDK v12 for Python.

Here is my sample code.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta  
from azure.storage.blob import generate_container_sas, ContainerSasPermissions
 
account_name = "<your account name>"  
account_key = "<your account key>"  
container_name = "<your container name, such as `test`>"  

# using generate_container_sas  
def get_img_url_with_container_sas_token(blob_name):  
container_sas_token = generate_container_sas(  
account_name=account_name,  
container_name=container_name,  
account_key=account_key,  
permission=ContainerSasPermissions(read=True),  
expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)  
)  
blob_url_with_container_sas_token = f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}?{container_sas_token}"  
return blob_url_with_container_sas_token

from azure.storage.blob import generate_blob_sas, BlobSasPermissions  

# using generate_blob_sas  
def get_img_url_with_blob_sas_token(blob_name):  
blob_sas_token = generate_blob_sas(  
account_name=account_name,  
container_name=container_name,  
blob_name=blob_name,  
account_key=account_key,  
permission=ContainerSasPermissions(read=True),  
expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)  
)  
blob_url_with_blob_sas_token = f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}?{blob_sas_token}"  
return blob_url_with_blob_sas_token

from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
  
@app.route("/showimg")  
@app.route("/showimg/<blob_name>")  
def hello_world(blob_name=None):  
img_url_with_sas_token = get_img_url_with_blob_sas_token(blob_name)  
# Or  
# img_url_with_sas_token = get_img_url_with_container_sas_token(blob_name)  
return render_template('showimage.html', img_url_with_sas_token=img_url_with_sas_token)

app.run()
```

And my `templates/showimage.html` is very simple as below.

```py
<html>  
<head>  
</head>  
<body>  
<img src="{{img_url_with_sas_token}}" />  
</body>  
</html>
```

To add the token to the URL of the blob, you would need to construct a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token with at least Read permission (to get SAS URL). You can display the contents of the blob by using this SAS URL in the front end.

You may either use generate container SAS to construct an SAS on a container that can be used with all blobs or use generate blob SAS to create a separate SAS for each blob in the list.

Please refer [Azure Storage Blobs client library](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/)